# Cannot display linear gradient as a background image on a html page

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://w3.org/2000/svg">
     <title> Background </title>
     <text>
      <LinearGradient id="g" x1="200%" x2="0%" y1="50%" y2="0%">
      <stop style = "stop-color: green;" offset="0"/>
      <stop style = "stop-color: white;" offset="1"/>
      </LinearGradient>
     </text>
     <rect style = "fill: url(#g);" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
    </svg>
```

The output of this code is either broken image, or the Title "Background" and I do not see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two issues which affect standalone SVG only

- the SVG namespace is incorrect so the file is not recognised as an SVG file. You're missing www from the namespace.
- standalone SVG files are case sensitive so we need to write linearGradient

And this one is a bug even when you embed SVG in html.

- you can't make a linearGradient the child of a `<text>` tag. We can use `<defs>` instead. In theory we could omit the `<defs>` tag, although I think Safari isn't keen on that.

which leaves us with this...

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title> Background </title>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="g" x1="200%" x2="0%" y1="50%" y2="0%">
        <stop style = "stop-color: green;" offset="0"/>
        <stop style = "stop-color: white;" offset="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect style = "fill: url(#g);" width = "100%" height = "100%"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `defs` for the gradient. You may also consider viewbox and width/height:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="200">
    <title> Background </title>
    <defs>
        <LinearGradient id="g" x1="200%" x2="0%" y1="50%" y2="0%">
        <stop style = "stop-color: green;" offset="0"/>
        <stop style = "stop-color: white;" offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#g)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I had that originally, but no dice

Comment: @BrandonBurchett try to add viewbox and width/height .. it's working fine in the snippet here

Comment: I see, okay. When I open it in chrome it says the XML file does not have any style information with it

Comment: @BrandonBurchett how you are opening it? you are saving the file as .svg ?

Comment: Yes, background.svg, opening in chrome. I open other svgs and it's the image, here nothing.

Comment: @BrandonBurchett in this case why you don't simply use CSS gradient?

Comment: The SVG background is what my instructor wants.

Comment: @BrandonBurchett can you show me the other SVG, how they look?

Comment: @BrandonBurchett update your question with more detail and describe that it works for some SVG and not this particular one ... the SVG wizard will come soon and you will get you answer ;) I cannot help more here